# Select the newest change of the value

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have table INTERESTRATE:

```
CustId   Dt   IntRt 
1      201401   1
1      201402   2
1      201403   2
1      201404   2
1      201405   3
2      201401   1
2      201402   1
2      201403   2
2      201404   2
```

and i want to select for each CustID the last date of change of the IntRt and what was the change. Format like Dt,original IntRt, new IntRt.

So the select will return:

```
CustID  Change
1       201405,2,3
2       201403,1,2
```

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I tried queries like :

> Select max(Dt) from INTERESTRATE where custID = CustID and IntRt <>
>   IntRt

I know its obviously wrong , because im comparing the same values so it will return nothing, but i dont know what to do different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    rn = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY Dt DESC), *
  FROM INTERESTRATE
)
SELECT
  c1.CustId,
  c1.Dt,
  OriginalIntRt = (SELECT TOP 1 IntRt FROM cte c2 WHERE c1.CustId = c2.CustId AND c1.IntRt <> c2.IntRt ORDER BY dt DESC),
  c1.IntRt AS NewIntRt
FROM cte c1
WHERE c1.rn = 1
```